# Django : non iterable object into QuerySet

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to unpack a non iterable object into a QuerySet.
This is my code :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.response import Response
...
@api_view(['GET'])
def order(request):
    '''Get all the orders for a user'''
    context = []
    if request.GET.get('user'): #If we make a request type ?user=...
        id_user = request.GET.get('user')
        user = get_object_or_404(member_area, pk=id_user)
        if request.GET.get('order'): #If we make specific request on an order
            id_order = request.GET.get('order')
            orders = commande.objects.get(id=id_order, membre_id=id_user)
        else:
            orders = commande.objects.filter(membre_id=id_user)
                              ...
```

I would like to unpack **orders** when I get in the request `...?user=1&order=2`.
Thanks by advance

Comment: what you mean by unpacking and what do you intend to do with it? This will help to answer it more appropriately.

Comment: I want to have a QuerySet object to make a JSON file with the data. For exemple, I would like to get data like the date or the price of the order with ```orders.date``` or ```orders.price```

Comment: `orders` is already a queryset.

Comment: use **`objects.filter(....)`** instead of `objects.get(...)`

Comment: @VishalSingh ```order``` is only a QuerySet when I don't get ```?order=``` in my request

Comment: @ArakkalAbu But I would like to return a 404 error when I don't find result

Comment: yes I missed that, change that to `filter` instead of `get` as suggested by @ArakkalAbu

Comment: @VishalSingh Yes but with ```get_object_or_404``` I return a 404 error when I don't find result instead of a 500 error

Comment: I think you need to post your full code in order for us to suggest any better alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.response import Response
...
@api_view(['GET'])
def order(request):
    '''Get all the orders for a user'''
    context = []
    if request.GET.get('user'): #If we make a request type ?user=...
        id_user = request.GET.get('user')
        user = get_object_or_404(member_area, pk=id_user)
        if request.GET.get('order'): #If we make specific request on an order
            id_order = request.GET.get('order')
            orders = commande.objects.filter(id=id_order, membre_id=id_user)
            if not orders.exists():
                return HttpResponse(status=500) #Or 404
        else:
            orders = commande.objects.filter(membre_id=id_user)
```

Instead of .get() you can use .filter() and then raise an error if it's empty